# How to create subset of data based on multiple matching field values in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that pulls emails using EWS managed API, reads their subject, from address, to address, and internetmessageheaders.  Within the email read loop it loads all this information into a datatable.

I need to grab all the above information for each message and populate an array or datatable based on the from address.  Then I'll check for relay information and send the whole list based on from address to a target address.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to build the from address lists.  I've tried turning the datatable data into a hashtable and then using a `sort|get-unique` to get a list of the unique from addresses but have not been able to use this information to correctly build the from address array.  I've tried looping through using a `select-string $_ -allmatches` but haven't gotten anywhere.

Here is part of my code, It creates the datatable and populates it using information from each email.

```
$msgTable = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “Messages”
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Subject,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn From,([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn To,([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Relay,([string])
$msgTable.columns.add($col1)
$msgTable.columns.add($col2)
$msgTable.columns.add($col3)
$msgTable.columns.add($col4)

$frItemResult = $PublicFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)
# Loop through view results and mark read
$frItemResult | ForEach-object{
if($_.HasAttachments ) {
$_.Load()
"Report Subject: $($_.Subject)"
# Loop through attachments, extract info
$_.Attachments | ForEach-object  {
if($_.Name -notmatch "ATT00001"){
$_.Load($attPropset)

$row = $msgTable.NewRow();$row.Subject = $($_.item.Subject); $row.From = ($_.item.From.address); $row.To = $($_.item.ToRecipients.address); $row.Relay = "$($_.Item.InternetMessageHeaders | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*received*"})";$msgTable.Rows.Add($row)
```

Here is what `$msgTable` looks like after data is populated.

```
Subject                          From                             To                               Relay                           
-------                          ----                             --                               -----                           
Message1                        user1@company.com           recipient1@yahoo.com               Received-SPF=pass (domain of ...
Message2                        user2@company.com           recipient2@comcast.net             Received=from imta27.mailguys...
Message2                        user2@company.com           recipient3@yahoo.com               Received-SPF=pass (domain of ...
Message3                        user3@company.com           recipient4@sbcglobal.net           Received-SPF=pass (domain of ...
```

I need to be able to grep out all the information for user2@company.com to another variable and do the same for any number of other repeating or non-repeating from addresses.

I'll then take each of the from address variables and send it to the target recipient.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Group-Object, you can then run a foreach loop against each grouping:

```
$Grouping = $msgTable | Group-Object -Property From
foreach ($Group in $Grouping)
{
    Write-Host $Group.Name -ForegroundColor "Green"
    $Group.Group | ft -Auto
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool exercise! This is how I would approach it...

> ...I need to be able to grep out all the information for
>   user2@company.com to another variable

```
$patternMatches = $msgTable | select-string -pattern 'user2@company.com'
```

> ...and do the same for any number of other repeating or non-repeating
>   from addresses.

```
$uniqueEmails = $msgTable | Select-Object From -Unique

foreach ($email in $uniqueEmails) {
    $patternMatches = $msgTable | Select-Object -property * | select-string -pattern $email
}
```

I know this isn't exactly right, but it should push you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the response; this is where I was heading but hadn't gotten there as completely as your second example.